# android viewpager onTitleClick disable switch

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with pagerstrip.
I need to disallow the title onClick change (not to change if I click on the title).

Answer (score 1):

you could just set the OnClickListener to null e.g.

```
view.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

okay here is my solution:

1.) need a custom pagerstrip:

```
CustomPagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip;
```

the CustomPagerTabStrip class:

```
public class CustomPagerTabStrip extends PagerTabStrip {

    private boolean isTabSwitchEnabled;

    public CustomPagerTabStrip(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPagerTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.isTabSwitchEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("ENable?? " + isTabSwitchEnabled);
        if (this.isTabSwitchEnabled) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.isTabSwitchEnabled) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setTabSwitchEnabled(boolean isSwipeEnabled) {
        this.isTabSwitchEnabled = isSwipeEnabled;
    }
  }
```

than you can easily enable or disable it:

```
pagerTabStrip.setTabSwitchEnabled(true);
```